# Add a different item from a list to each cell in a dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

Given a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

I want to make a list of sequential that has as many elements as there are rows in the dataframe

```
l = [i for i in range(df['A'].count())]
```

And then add each element of the list (as a string) onto the end of a single column in the dataframe.

```
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: str(x) + str(l[i]))
```

Does not work, as it adds the whole list as a string to each value as opposed to one value of the list per value in the dataframe.

Essentially, I want to transform

```
A    B    C
23   16   85
 9   74   12
99   24   83
```

to

```
A     B    C
231   16   85
 92   74   12
993   24   83
```

So anyway to do that would be fine.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How do you want to handle 2- and more-digit row numbers? Append all digits or only the last one?

Comment: It should append all digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
df['A'] = df.A.astype(str) + (df.index+1).astype(str)

>>> df
     A   B   C
0  231  16  85
1   92  74  12
2  993  24  83
```

That's assuming your dataframe has a regular `RangeIndex`. If not, you can use:

```
df['A'] = df.A.astype(str) + (df.reset_index().index + 1).astype(str)
```

Or

```
df['A'] = df.A.astype(str) + (pd.RangeIndex(len(df)) + 1).astype(str)
```